# Xamarin iOS App is not getting lanuched after clicking on Short dynamic link created using firebase console

Tags: ios, firebase, xamarin.ios, firebase-dynamic-links

I am trying open my app using firebase short dynamic link. I have followed below steps to implement

First, i have created the Firebase project and app with same bundle id,then i have created one dynamic link for the app. As shown in screenshot.

firebase Dynamic Link Screenshot

[image]

In my project i added GoogleService-Info.plist of particular app which having bundle id and developer id of my app.
Also added xamarin firebase iOS component for dynamic link from below link:
https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/firebaseiosdynamiclinks

Also i have enabled associate domain and provided domain as "**applinks:aku4q.app.goo.gl**"

then i added url types in info list with custom url scheme **myapp://**

After following all these steps, i typed custom url scheme in safari, app is getting opened, But whenever i am clicking the short dynamic link, not able to open.

Please suggest me any solution to open xamarin iOS app using firebase short dynamic link.